# Set iOS Application to be a default browser

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I am wondering if there is any way to make my iOS application show up as a default browser like google or safari. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you jailbreak, apparently you can.

If you want your app to be found in the app store, nope.

You can't set your app as the default browser programmatically (as that would be a security risk; imagine a malicious app changing settings to spoof as a browser to collect passwords or bank info).

And the ways you can typically get your app to be more accessible is to use extensions and the system "Share" sheet.

[Here's an article that talks about all these techniques](https://www.howtogeek.com/204911/how-to-choose-your-default-applications-on-an-iphone-or-ipad/).

Comment: how can I have it listed as a browser? for example google chrome browser is often prompted when you're opening a link, as well as safari